# pushing data to an array from an async function in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I want to store objects to an array. I am using a package called finnhub to search for data, right now I am pushing empty information to the array and need help with async await  (I think) to make it work properly. Here is my code:

router.get("/execute", async function(req, res){

```
let positions = [];


try {
    
    let unixTimestamp = new Date();
    let today = parseInt((new Date(unixTimestamp).getTime()/1000).toFixed(0));
    let twoDays = today - (2 * 86400);
    let ignites = [];
    
    
    for(const stock of stocks) {
        
        finnhubClient.stockCandles(stock, "1", twoDays, today, {}, async (error, data, response)  => {
            try {
                let info = await data;
                
                let total = 0;
                for(let i = 0; i < info.h.length; i++) {
                    let barPriceChange = await parseFloat((info.h[i] - info.l[i]));
                    total += barPriceChange;
                }
                let ignite = await {symbol: stock, avgBar: total/info.h.length};
                
                ignites.push(ignite);
                

            } catch(err) {
                console.log("ERROR", err.message);
            }
        });
            
    }
    console.log(ignites);
    

    
} catch(err) {
    console.log("ERROR", err.message)
}
```

});

Comment: why are you doing `await data`, `await parseFloat` and `await {}`?

Answer (score 0):

Your gonna need to create a Promise function and execute it:

```js
const executeAsync = async (stock, twoDays, today) => new Promise((res, rej) => {
    finnhubClient.stockCandles(stock, "1", twoDays, today, {}, async (error, data, response)  => {
        try {
            let info = data;

            let total = 0;
            for(let i = 0; i < info.h.length; i++) {
                let barPriceChange = await parseFloat((info.h[i] - info.l[i]));
                total += barPriceChange;
            }
            let ignite = await {symbol: stock, avgBar: total/info.h.length};

            res(ignite);
        } catch(err) {
            rej(err.message);
        }
    });
});
```

and then use it:

```
let unixTimestamp = new Date();
let today = parseInt((new Date(unixTimestamp).getTime()/1000).toFixed(0));
let twoDays = today - (2 * 86400);
let ignites = [];


for(const stock of stocks) {
   const response = await executeAsync(stock, twoDays, today);
   ignites.push(response)
}
```

Comment: first recieved SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'return'.

Comment: Removed return and it worked, do you know what that means, I am concerned about future development on this application and how it could be affected. Any where you could guide me?

Comment: Your right, I wrote the return by mistake, its function expression so it dosent need return.
Anyway, its a Promise, read about it.